# What is wrong in this line? Gesture recognizer -> pinch

Tags: iphone, warnings, uigesturerecognizer

In following line I get the warning **"expected identifier before '[' token"**

```
gestureRecognizer.[pictureElement piece].transform =
CGAffineTransformScale(gestureRecognizer.[pictureElement
piece].transform, gestureRecognizer.scale, gestureRecognizer.scale);
```

I guess it is a stupid mistake but I am sitting here for hours not finding the problem.
In the following you see the whole method

```
- (IBAction)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{ 
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        gestureRecognizer.[pictureElement piece].transform = CGAffineTransformScale(gestureRecognizer.[pictureElement piece].transform, gestureRecognizer.scale, gestureRecognizer.scale); 
        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];  
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
If I forgot to add a bracket, it would be more than one warning.

**2nd Update**
pictureElement is a class and piece is the attribute of the class. 
So I want the Gesture react on the attribute piece of my class pictureElement.
 PictureElement inherits from UIView and piece is a instance of UIView

**3rd Update** 
I think there is nothing wrong in my gestures, because if I add *self.view* instead of *[pictureElement piece]* my screen starts to move and to react on my gestures

Thank you in advance

Comment: `gestureRecognizer.[pictureElement piece].transform` looks really wrong. And `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` does not have property named `[pictureElement piece]`. Do you have some `pictureElement` which you want to be available in `pinchDetected:`?

Comment: see above, I edit my question to answer your question

Comment: Seeing your interface would help a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't `gestureRecognizer.pictureElement.piece.transform` work?

Comment: sadly not :( I have try it before

Comment: I still do not understand what do you mean by `gesture.[...]`. You may write `gesture.view`, `[gesture locationInView:gesture.view]`, etc. So, in case your `gesture` was added to `pictureElement`, you should write `PicureElement *pictureElement = gesture.view; pictureElement .transform = ...;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gestureRecognizer.[pictureElement piece].transform =` doesn't make sense. Things of the form `x.y = z`, where `x` is an object instance, translate into `[x setY:z]` or something very similar at compile time -- i.e. a message `setY:z` is sent to instance `x`.

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but is the case that the `gestureRecognizer.` part is spurious and shouldn't be there? The following code would perhaps make more sense (although wouldn't necessarily be correct):

```
- (IBAction)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{ 
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        [pictureElement piece].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([pictureElement piece].transform, gestureRecognizer.scale, gestureRecognizer.scale); 
        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];  
    }
}
```

As a side note on style matters, consider sticking consistently to either dot notation (`x.y`) or message-passing notation (`[x y]`) in any one place when you're dealing purely with properties. For example, instead of writing:

```
[pictureElement piece].transform = thing
```

you could stick to all dot notation, like so:

```
pictureElement.piece.transform = thing
```

or you could make it all message-passing format, like so:

```
[[pictureElement piece] setTransform:thing]
```

Comment: Thank you, you're really good. I have no warning nor crashes, but my UIView is still not reacting on my gestures. It wears me down

Comment: Put an NSLog into your pinchDetected method. Is it definitely getting called when you do a pinch?

Comment: And also NSLog the gestureRecognizer.scale value, to see what it actually is.

Comment: And what class is pictureElement an instance of? Is it a custom class?

Comment: The NSLog methods in my pinchDetected are called but if I add something like NSLog("pictureElement piece ist %@",[pictureElement.piece description]); my app crashes

Comment: pictureElement is an instance of UIView like I mentioned it in my question